# Surveyjs: getting the previous question title for question generation

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to create a survey based on Surveyjs. And I am thinking about obtaining the previous question titles to generate questions. For example, the first two questions are 'do you like reading' and 'do you like writing'. If the answers are different on the questions, the following question will be 'why do you like reading but don't like writing?'. I try to use the expression like {questionName}.title or {questionName.title} to obtain the titles, but it doesn't work. Is there any solution for this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think that's supported, but you could achieve it with "visibleIf" expressions for the follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
pages": [
    {
      "name": "page1",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "radiogroup",
          "name": "car",
          "isRequired": true,
          "title": "Langue",
          "colCount": 4,
          "choicesOrder": "asc",
          "choices": [
            "car1",
            "car2",
            "car3"
        
          ]
        }, {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "name": "bestcar",
          "isRequired": true,
          "visibleIf": "{car}='car1'",
          "title": " ",
          "choicesFromQuestion": "car",
          "choicesFromQuestionMode": "selected"
        },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).